# How to check if a string contains a pattern separated by whitespace?

Tags: c#, regex, string

How to check if a string contains a pattern separated by whitespace?

Examples:

```
"abc  ef    ds       ab  "
```

Now I would like to check if the given string consists only of the pattern `[a-z]` separated by whitespace. My try: `^\s*[a-z]*\s*$`. But this checks only whitespace in the beginning and end, not if the whitespaces is used for separation of the content.

Comment: What do you mean by pattern seperated? It means 2 whitespace then 3 then 4 etc..?

Comment: The whitespace between pattern [a-z] can be arbritrary.

Comment: Would `" "` be a valid string? Or `"abc"`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, both are valid.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^[a-z\s]+$/
```

Comment: And now that we know even a single space is valid, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\s|[a-z])*$
```

Zero or more case characters that are either whitespace, or A-Z.

If you want to make sure there's at least one thing other than white space, then:

```
^\s*[a-z]+(\s*|[a-z])*$
```

Zero or more whitespace, at least one character A-Z, then the same as above.